# Revolution Slider in visual composer row: navigation not working

Tags: wordpress, layout, navigation, revolution-slider, visual-composer

The revolution slider I embedded into my page's row here http://jungle-crisps.com/fr/la-gamme/ is displayed correctely, but the thumbnails links and navigation arrows are just not clickable, I don't get why. I tried to set the slider layout in full width on the page and the navigation worked tho.. Why is it that with the layout set on full width navigation works properly but doesn't when the slider is in a row (with layout width set to auto)?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow some general debug steps.

Ref. [General debug steps](https://perishablepress.com/how-to-troubleshoot-wordpress/):

- **Create a Complete Backup of Your WordPress Site (Files and database)**
- Clear browser's cache.
- Deactivate All Plugins Installed on Your    Website, activate one by one and test.
- Switch to a Default WordPress Theme.
- Update theme and plugins to latest.

Google for: revolution slider arrows not showing (Looks like a common issue)

PS. 
- I had the same issue before; fixed with CSS.
- Your site shows some jQuery errors.